# Is it possible to have variable attribute names in Java? If not, why?

Tags: java

I'd like to know whether it is possible to create attributes based on variable names. To be more specific please see the following example.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    String number+i = i;
}
```

That means every attribute would have the base name 'number' extended by it's value i. So I could for example do the following (assuming these would be stored and accessible, as well as ignoring the fact that attribute / variable names should not contain numbers, but you get the idea):

```
System.out.println(number5); //You could do the same example with Strings and not numbers
```

Obviously the first part does not compile but I think that excerpt makes clear what I'm asking about. Are there any program languages where this would be possible? Or is there a trick in Java to make this possible?

However what's the reason behind it not to have it? Obviously if this would be possible an attribute could store two variable values (the name of the attribute and the value itself) which might lead to confusion. But is this the only reason not to have it or is there anything else?

Comment: Why not?  Because [arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) already exist in Java.

Comment: Is it as simple as that? Makes sense somehow definitly eventhough arrays are a little bit different in a semantic way. Arrays are index based but from my point of view you could also refer to an attribute with a String for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that simple creating variables names as `int number+1 = 10, int number+2 = 20...` is not possible because it could be too confusing if you try to assign value of `number+1` to another variable. Look at this: `int another = number+1` . In this case compiler wouldn't know if to look for variable with name `number` and to increment it or to look for variable with name `number+1`.

But reflection offers you a little bit of what you are trying to achieve, but I would suggest simply using arrays or Map, these option look more clear, more simple and I think that they offer you more safety that using reflection. Anyway, look at this simple example of using reflection to dynamically use names of fields (note that in this case field need to be declared as public):

```
public class Test {
    public int field1 = 1;
    public int field2 = 2;
    public int field3 = 3;
    // this method changes values assigned to field1, field2 and field3:
    public void setFields()
            throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException, NoSuchFieldException, SecurityException {
        for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
            Test.class.getField("field" + i).set(this, 25); // Here is what you may be looking for, you dynamically find field1, field2, ...
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
            throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException, NoSuchFieldException, SecurityException {
        Test t = new Test();
        for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
            int j = (Test.class.getField("field" + i).getInt(t)); // Another example
            System.out.print(j + " ");
        }
        t.setFields();
        for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
            int j = (Test.class.getField("field" + i).getInt(t));
            System.out.print(j + " ");
        }
    }

}
```

Output you get when executing this program:

```
1 2 3 25 25 25
```

As you see, when changing values assigned to `field1`, `field2` and `field3` and also when printing them to the console, I didn't have to use their names, I could use loop and concatenate String `field` with the index of `i` that I got from "for" loop. Anyway, when declaring these variables, I had no possibility to write their names any other way, than just typing `field1, etc...`

Answer (score 4):

You should look into Map (and for example HashMap implementation), which would allow you to have dynamic keys for your properties.

```
Map<String, Object> newMap = new HashMap<>();
newMap.put("whatever", "Value 1");
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    newMap.put(number+i, i);
}
```

Comment: Good point, but what I'm aiming at is why do i have store these attributes with variable names into a datastructure like a map? Why can I not initialize them simply inside of a method?

Comment: @LOLWTFasdasdasdad - What do you mean by "initialize them inside of a method"?

Comment: I'm referring towards local method variables. Variables which are only visible inside of a method body. To be more specific: If i have a method I do want to initialize a bunch of variables with different names and values but I do not want to safe them in an array or in a map. So why can't i take a loop and simply initialize them one by one with different names? Is this only to avoid syntactic ambiguity? (See D M's answer)

Comment: @LOLWTFasdasdasdad - The map `newMap` in this approach can be a local variable.

Comment: @LOLWTFasdasdasdad - "So why can't I ..." - because there's no need to - the language is designed (as most languages are) such that it's not necessary (or worse, it would be counter-intuitive) to do so.

Comment: @LOLWTFasdasdasdad In the worst case, you would have to look into "code generation", (often use for example to generate code responding to an API) but I really dont think you need this. Just use a map as a property of your class and you're good to go.

Answer (score 1):

One reason not to do it is that it makes code ambiguous.  A simple example:

```
int number = 7;
int number2 = 5;
int x = 2;
number = number+x
```

What does that last line mean?  Are we setting `number` equal to itself plus 2, or are we setting it equal to `number2`?

Arrays have the bracket syntax, which separates the index from the variable so they don't get mashed together.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do looks like creating dynamically variables (in the loop here) and have a way to reuse them then.
Java is a strongly typed language and doesn't have a kind of global context as in JavaScript.
So it doesn't provide such a feature.
Introducing global context to store variables is not advised as it introduces  potential variables collisions.

So in the variables declared in your loop have as lifespan the current iteration :

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    String number+i = i;
}
```

> Obviously if this would be possible an attribute could store two
>   variable values (the name of the attribute and the value itself) which
>   might lead to confusion.

Not an attribute but a variable and the `PhilippeAuriach` answer goes to this direction by introducing the `HashMap`.